# Start Over button in Gupshup chatbot

Tags: back

We w[image]ould like to know how the Start Over button was used in one of the examples in Gupshup chatbot. Attaching the image for your reference.

We are actually intrested in allowing the user to go back to the main menu by using the button option. We have seen videos with user tying back. And also we have used the linking options.

Thanks
Manjiri

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will explain in detail what my query is: I have designed a bot to make user understand how to view the sample. What steps he needs to follow. For example I have used quick responses so that user does not ask many questions instead selects from the options provided. Digital Content has two categories A and B. A further has 3 sub categories. After reading a bout the sub category, if the user wants to return to A, how do I do that. In one of your examples, you have shown the start over button. I need to know how to use it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information there. Thanks